# Why is python random.seed nondeterministic on non-primative inputs?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

The following code on Python 3.8 always prints 18 (I've tried this on 3 different machines):

```
import random
random.seed(1)
print(random.randint(1, 100))
```

However, calling seed with a non-primative in Python 3.8 is semi-nondeterministic:

```
import random
from datetime import date
random.seed(date(2022, 5, 18))
print(random.randint(1, 100))
```

I say semi-nondeterministic because if I run the code multiple times within the same Python process (such as a Python terminal), I get the same random number.  However, but if I restart the Python process, I get a different number.

Clearly it's not using `id` of the object, since that changes every time I make a new date object so I wouldn't get the same result within a Python terminal.

What, then, is going on?

Comment: I get a deprecation warning when I try to use `random.seed(date(2022, 5, 18))`. `date` is not a supported seed type.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed—Since 3.9, the seed is required to be an int, float, string, bytes, bytearray, or None.

Comment: As an aside, "complex type" isn't really a standard terminology in Python -- most people would think you are talking about the actual `complex` type.

Answer (score 3):

Using `seed` with types other than NoneType, int, float, str, bytes, or bytearray is deprecated starting in Python 3.9, likely due to this behavior.

By casting a date to a string, the code becomes deterministic.  The following code always prints 46:

```
import random
from datetime import date
random.seed(str(date(2022, 5, 18)))
print(random.randint(1, 100))
```

What is going on under the hood is likely that `seed` is using a hash of the complex object.  The following code has the same behavior as passing a Date to `seed`, namely that it's result is deterministic within a single Python process but different between Python processes:

```
from datetime import date
print(hash(date(2022, 5, 18)))
```

Note that `random.seed` doesn't literally use `hash`, since the following gives different results (99% of the time):

```
random.seed(date(2022, 5, 18))
a = random.randint(1, 100)

random.seed(hash(date(2022, 5, 18)))
b = random.randint(1, 100)
print(a, b)
```

Comment: I find that even `int` fails to make a reproducible seed, and `str()` does not help it.